# Javascript string split using pattern Google Maps Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a string like this I need to convert it into a array of objects.

```
abc =   "new google.maps.LatLng('55.7386', '37.6068'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.4964', '-0.1224'), new google.maps.LatLng('31.5', '34.75'), new google.maps.LatLng('32.0666', '34.765'), new google.maps.LatLng('30.0355', '31.223'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.4964', '-0.1224'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.8431', '8.0917'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.8431', '8.0917'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('48.8582', '2.3387000000000002'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.5985', '18.1452'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.296', '17.3957'), new google.maps.LatLng('22.9933', '120.2036'), new google.maps.LatLng('3.1456', '101.645'), new google.maps.LatLng('35.69', '139.69'), new google.maps.LatLng('-27.5215', '153.0123'), new google.maps.LatLng('10.8142', '106.6438'), new google.maps.LatLng('37.5112', '126.97409999999999'), new google.maps.LatLng('33.6064', '130.4181'), new google.maps.LatLng('39.9289', '116.3883'), new google.maps.LatLng('32.0617', '118.7778'), new google.maps.LatLng('21.0333', '105.85'), new google.maps.LatLng('28.6', '77.2')"
```

I need the output like this

```
    var array = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435)
];
```

Comment: Where does that string comes? Explain the context please. Usually you can send a list of coordinates and create LatLng object in js

Comment: The string is coming as a response from some server I have to create the frontend I dont have control over the response coming from the server

Comment: Tell the backend guy he's doing it wrong. He should send into fronted a list of tuples which are the coordinates. For example a list like : `[(37.782, -122.447), (37.782, -122.448)]` . And then you may use that list to create the LatLng objects.

Comment: Sending a string like that is bad practice and also hard to maintain.

Comment: I have no idea about the backend I just have an url if I ping it I get this response. I guess backend is some private server which I have no idea who has written it

Comment: If you really want to use it that way, a regex is your best option.

Comment: Yes I have tried many regex options, Im not getting it

Comment: Post also your solution that is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments above are correct that this is far from an ideal backend API; it would be safer to send only the lat/long coordinates and construct the google.maps calls in the browser.

Assuming the API isn't under your control, however:

First split that string into an array on `", new"` (and replace the "new" in all but the first item) to get an array of strings.

If you want to execute those strings as javascript statements, you would then need to iterate through the array and `eval()` each line.  `eval()` is a dangerous tool, since it will execute whatever is fed to it, which is obviously a risk with unsecured input into which a malicious user may have injected arbitrary code.  Make sure you confirm that what you're about to `eval()` matches what you expect to be `eval()`ing, as strictly as possible.

```js
abc = "new google.maps.LatLng('55.7386', '37.6068'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.4964', '-0.1224'), new google.maps.LatLng('31.5', '34.75'), new google.maps.LatLng('32.0666', '34.765'), new google.maps.LatLng('30.0355', '31.223'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.4964', '-0.1224'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.8431', '8.0917'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.8431', '8.0917'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('48.8582', '2.3387000000000002'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.5985', '18.1452'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.296', '17.3957'), new google.maps.LatLng('22.9933', '120.2036'), new google.maps.LatLng('3.1456', '101.645'), new google.maps.LatLng('35.69', '139.69'), new google.maps.LatLng('-27.5215', '153.0123'), new google.maps.LatLng('10.8142', '106.6438'), new google.maps.LatLng('37.5112', '126.97409999999999'), new google.maps.LatLng('33.6064', '130.4181'), new google.maps.LatLng('39.9289', '116.3883'), new google.maps.LatLng('32.0617', '118.7778'), new google.maps.LatLng('21.0333', '105.85'), new google.maps.LatLng('28.6', '77.2')";

var arr = abc.split(', new'); // Can't split just on the comma, since there are commas inside the data itself

for (var i=1; i<arr.length;i++) {
   arr[i] = "new" + arr[i]; // replace the "new" keywords that the 'split' removed
}

// We now have an array of strings:
console.log(arr);

// sanitize before eval()ing each entry in the array:
arr.forEach(function(row) {
  // does this row contain what we expect it to, and nothing else?
  if (row.match(/^new google.maps.LatLng\('[\d\.\-]*?', '[\d\.\-]*?'\)$/)) {
    // it's safe to call eval(row) here
  } else {
    console.error("Unexpected input:",row);
  }
});
```

...All that said, rather than using `eval()` at all it might be safer (and easier, for that matter) to start out by throwing out everything in the API data except the latitude/longitude values, and constructing your google.maps calls from those:

```js
abc = "new google.maps.LatLng('55.7386', '37.6068'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.4964', '-0.1224'), new google.maps.LatLng('31.5', '34.75'), new google.maps.LatLng('32.0666', '34.765'), new google.maps.LatLng('30.0355', '31.223'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.4964', '-0.1224'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.8431', '8.0917'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.8431', '8.0917'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('51.2993', '9.491'), new google.maps.LatLng('48.8582', '2.3387000000000002'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.5985', '18.1452'), new google.maps.LatLng('49.296', '17.3957'), new google.maps.LatLng('22.9933', '120.2036'), new google.maps.LatLng('3.1456', '101.645'), new google.maps.LatLng('35.69', '139.69'), new google.maps.LatLng('-27.5215', '153.0123'), new google.maps.LatLng('10.8142', '106.6438'), new google.maps.LatLng('37.5112', '126.97409999999999'), new google.maps.LatLng('33.6064', '130.4181'), new google.maps.LatLng('39.9289', '116.3883'), new google.maps.LatLng('32.0617', '118.7778'), new google.maps.LatLng('21.0333', '105.85'), new google.maps.LatLng('28.6', '77.2')";

var latlongs = abc.match(/'[\d\.\-]*?'/g);  // Array of all quoted numbers
for (var i=0; i<latlongs.length-1; i=i+2) {
  console.log("new google.maps.LatLng("+latlongs[i]+","+latlongs[i+1]+");");
  //new google.maps.LatLng(latlongs[i],latlongs[i+1]);
}
```